# Exporting Chinese characters to CSV file results in it being converted to question marks

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

We are exporting Lotus Notes documents to CSV file. Some of the field have Chinese characters in them. They are visible in Lotus Notes (though I don't understand them) but when we export them to CSV file they are converted to question marks. Below is the code snippet I am using for export:

```
fieldNames = Split("Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4", ",")

Set stream = session.CreateStream

If stream.Open(csvFileName) Then
    Call stream.Truncate()

    Forall f In fieldNames
        Call stream.WriteText("""" + doc.GetItemValue(f)(0) + """,")
    End Forall
    .....
    .....
    .....
End If
```

Here if the field `Field1` contains Chinese characters and it is exported, they are converted to question marks. How to properly export Chinese characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a charset "UTF-16" for stream: `stream.Open(csvFileName, "UTF-16")` then it works for Chinese.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use `charset` while opening stream. But it didn't work with UTF-8 or Big5. Instead it worked with "UTF-16".

Comment: If you could update the answer to UTF-16 I would be glad to accept it.